# How can I perform a cluster analysis while checking for anticorrelation as well as correlation?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have data that is a matrix of z-scores.  Each row has zero average.  I am trying to perform a kmeans cluster analysis so as to assign each row to a cluster.  To take a very simplified example, in the matrix:

```
[0, -1, 1, 0]
[0, -1, 1, 0]
[0, 1, -1, 0]
[1, 1, -1, -1]
[-1, -1, 1, 1]
```

(Except the actual z-score data would have a variance of 1 in each row.)

Python should recognize that the top two rows are in one cluster.  I can do this with sklearn.cluster.KMeans.  However, now I want it to detect "anticorrelation" and classify the third row together with the top two rows because it is simply the negative of them.  If I tell it to find two clusters, it should find one with the top three rows and another with the bottom two, because the bottom two are also negatives of one another.

One possible approach (perhaps) is if I could use a user-defined goodness-of-fit function that defines the distance of two points r1 and r2 as being the minimum of sqrt((r1+r2)**2) and sqrt((r1-r2)**2).  I might than want to know whether a given row has been used as its positive or negative version in its cluster.

Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: It looks like scipy.cluster.hierarchy.fclusterdata
allows for a "metric" parameter unlike kmeans.  Maybe I just need to use hierarchical clustering instead?

Comment: Yes. Don't use kmeans here.

Comment: Thanks!  I ended up using Affinity Propagation.  When I used hierarchical clustering, it resulted in some very weird clusters for some reason.